# Vue.Draggable : Use component inside draggable transition-group

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I'm having trouble trying to use the Vue.Draggable library. I would like to use a component inside my draggable while keeping the transition-group. It's working without the transition group but whenever Im adding the transition-group tag with the animation name its not working anymore. My components elements are not showing up and I'm having this error :

```js
TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting '__draggable_context')
```

Here is my code :

```js
      <draggable :list="teams" item-key="idteam" tag="transition-group" :component-data="{name:'fade'}>
        <template #item="{ element, index }">
          <my-team :id="element.idteam" :name="element.teamName" :index="index">
          </my-team
        ></template>
      </draggable>
```

Any idea how could I make all work together ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Any chance you got this working? I'm facing the same issue right now and Rizkia's answer isn't doing the trick

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is still open on github and didn't get any fix :  
https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next/issues/188
If you really want to use transitions you can use the following package that fix the issue : https://www.npmjs.com/package/zhyswan-vuedraggable. I used it in a vue 3 project and its working !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `:animation="200"`; only adding `tag="transition-group"` is not enough.